# JQuery: How to select a specific input wrapped in a TD inside a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table, whose rows and td's are created with a foreach. So there is no predicting how many rows there might be. Each row has two buttons accompanied by an two adjacent input fields. See image:[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J9jI.jpg)  When you click a button, I need to grab the value inside it's adjacent input which is wrapped in a td. I have tried everything: prev(), closest(), eg(). And I can not figure out how to isolate the specific input *on click*. The best I have achieved is applying some css to ALL the inputs, but not the specific partnered input.

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($registeredChildren as $child)
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-2"><a href="'/getchild/'+ {{$child->child_id}}">{{$child->childFirstName}}</a>&nbsp &nbsp {{$child->childLastName}}</td>

                    <!--========TIME IN===========-->
                    <td class="col-3 pb-2 timeIn">
                        <input id="{{$child->child_id}}" class=" form-control " value="{{$child->timeIn}}" style="text-align:center;"  type="text">
                    </td>

                    <td><button class="btn btn-outline-success timeInReset">Reset</button></td>

                    <!-- //========TIME Out ===========//-->
                    <td class="col-3 pb-2"><input style="text-align:center;" class="form-control " type="text" ></td>
                    <td><button id="timeOut/{{$child->child_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-success out">Reset</button></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
           </tbody>
```

**Script - This Does Not Work!**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button.timeInReset").click( function () {

 $(this).closest("td.timeIn>input").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` doesn't look up sibling elements, but from current level up the DOM tree for parents.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
> selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
> ancestors in the DOM tree

```
$("button.timeInReset").click( function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td.timeIn>input").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

Comment: You are a rock star! Thank you !